# How do I write a unit test for this class using JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

This is my first unit test I am writing from scratch. I want to test the 5 conditions (`Member`, `MeetingActivity`, `ServiceActivity`, `LetterActivity` and `ReceiptActivity`). I used the eclipse shortcut to generate the JUnit test case. I've read articles on JUnit testing and still need some guidance.  Here's what I have so far.

How do I call the method to test the conditions?

```
@Test
public void testBuild() {

    Member memberActivity(String memberId) {
        Member activity = new Member();
        activity.setDeliveryType("Some Delivery Type");
        activity.setDocumentType("Some Document Type");

        return activity; 
    }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
public class MessageBuilder {

    private final EventPayload messagePayload;

    public MessageBuilder(){
        messagePayload = new EventPayload();
    }

    public EventPayload build(Activity event) {


        createBaseActivity(event);

        if (event instanceof Member) {
            updateToMemberActivity(event);
            return messagePayload;
        }

        if (event instanceof MeetingActivity) {
            updateToMeetingActivity(event);
            return messagePayload;
        }

        if (event instanceof ServiceActivity) {
            updateToServiceActivity(event);
            return messagePayload;
        }

        if (event instanceof LetterActivity) {
            updateToLetterActivity(event);
            return messagePayload;
        }

        if (event instanceof ReceiptActivity) {
            updateToReceiptActivity(event);
            return messagePayload;
        }

        return messagePayload;

    }


    private EventPayload createBaseActivity(Activity event) {

        messagePayload.setId(event.getId());
        messagePayload.setMemberId(event.getMemberId());
        messagePayload.setActivityDateTime(event.getActivityDateTime());

        messagePayload.setMemberIdIsPrimaryId(event.isMemberIdIsPrimaryId());
        messagePayload.setBuCode(event.getBuCode());
        messagePayload.setStateCode(event.getStateCode());
        messagePayload.setProductCode(event.getProductCode());
        messagePayload.setBusinessUnit(event.getBusinessUnit());

        messagePayload.setActivityType(event.getActivityType());
        messagePayload.setActivityIntent(event.getActivityIntent());
        messagePayload.setActivityAction(event.getActivityAction());
        messagePayload.setActivityStatus(event.getActivityStatus());
        messagePayload.setSourceSystem(event.getSourceSystem());
        messagePayload.setCaseId(event.getCaseId());
        messagePayload.setInitiatedBy(event.getInitiatedBy());
        messagePayload.setActivityDetailsPointer(event.getActivityDetailsPointer());
        messagePayload.setBusinessLine(event.getBusinessLine());

        messagePayload.setEventInstanceType(EventInstanceType.ACTIVITY.name());

        return messagePayload;
    }

    private EventPayload updateToMemberActivity(Activity event) {

        Member subTypedEvent = (Member) event;

        messagePayload.setDeliveryType(subTypedEvent.getDeliveryType());
        messagePayload.setDocumentType(subTypedEvent.getDocumentType());
        messagePayload.setEventInstanceType(EventInstanceType.MEMBER.name());

        return messagePayload;
    }

    private EventPayload updateToMeetingActivity(Activity event) {

        MeetingActivity subTypedEvent = (MeetingActivity) event;

        messagePayload.setDeliveryType(subTypedEvent.getDeliveryType());
        messagePayload.setDocumentType(subTypedEvent.getDocumentType());
        messagePayload.setEventInstanceType(EventInstanceType.MEETING.name());

        return messagePayload;
    }


    private EventPayload updateToServiceActivity(Activity event) {

        ServiceActivity subTypedEvent = (ServiceActivity) event;

        messagePayload.setReceivedBy(subTypedEvent.getReceivedBy());
        messagePayload.setConcernedParty(subTypedEvent.getConcernedParty());
        messagePayload.setSummary(subTypedEvent.getSummary());
        messagePayload.setEventInstanceType(EventInstanceType.SERVICE.name());

        return messagePayload;
    }


    private EventPayload updateToLetterActivity(Activity event) {

        LetterActivity subTypedEvent = (LetterActivity) event;

        messagePayload.setDeliveryType(subTypedEvent.getDeliveryType());
        messagePayload.setDocumentType(subTypedEvent.getDocumentType());
        messagePayload.setPaymentType(subTypedEvent.getPaymentType());
        messagePayload.setEventInstanceType(EventInstanceType.LETTER.name());

        return messagePayload;
    }

    private EventPayload updateToReceiptActivity(Activity event) {

        ReceiptActivity subTypedEvent = (ReceiptActivity) event;

        messagePayload.setPaymentType(subTypedEvent.getPaymentType());
        messagePayload.setEventInstanceType(EventInstanceType.RECEIPT.name());

        return messagePayload;
    }

}
```

I'm hoping for 100% coverage.

Comment: First you need to write a valid method. Your test code is not valid Java code: you may not define a method inside another method. Then, as for any test, the test method needs to execute the code you want to test, and check that the code did the right thing. So it needs to create a MessageBuilder, call its build() method, and check that the returned value is correct, according to your specifications. Note that your builder always mutates and returns the same object, which is most probably not what it should do.

Comment: Please edit your title to be more specific. What about this particular class raises your concern about writing a unit test? How is this Question distinct from all the many other questions about unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to cover all branches is to feed the class with mocks of the specific types.

There are many mocking frameworks in the Java-World where I prefer [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org)

When you have to specify a Mock for every *Activity* subclass.

e.g.

```
Member memberMock = Mockito.mock(Member.class);
```

and for every function called on this mock you should specify a return, that can be checked on the resulting *EventPayload* like this

```
when(memberMock.getId()).thenReturn(4711);
```

The short version of a test checking the Member branch would look like this:

```
Member memberMock = Mockito.mock(Member.class);
when(memberMock.getId()).thenReturn(4711);
//[...] here are the other calls mocked [...]


MessageBuilder messageBuilder = MessageBuilder();
EventPayload testSubject = messageBuilder.build(memberMock)

assertEquals(testSubject.id, 4711)
//[...] other asserts [...]
```

You also might considering to refactor the classes to gain a better architecture and with that a better testability, but that is beyond this explanation